# Convert DOM elements in a PDF into corrispective HTML elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, pdf, converters

Hy guys,

I'm looking forward to find a solution to convert DOM elements in a PDF (tables, boxes, lines, etc...) into the corrispective HTML elements.

I've tried many converter on the web, but they usually end up creating a background image for those elements, while i would like to have them converted into real html code.

Any Idea?
For instance JS or Python solutions are much better appreciated.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559804/pdf-to-dom-conversion-using-javascript

Comment: Unless your PDF files are Tagged (properly) then there are no DOM elements in a PDF. PDF is not DOM based like HTML/SVG, instead it is a stream of graphic operators, similar to OpenGL.
Either way, you should ask this here instead: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/